# How load my sharepoint designer custom list to my sharepoint site?

Tags: 2013, designer

I'm trying to make a custom list on sharepoint designer 2013, but I dont know how load my custom list on the sharepoint site :(, how can I load my custon form to sharepoint? I appreciate all answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you open SharePoint Designer(SPD) you are logging into the SharePoint site you are making changes to. Everything you do in designer is saved on your site. There is no need to load anything.. you just have to save it.

To make a custom list in designer:

- Go to lists and libraries on the left navigation bar
- At the top bar in SPD Click on the Custom List button
- Give it a name and hit ok.
- Now on the right side under Lists you will see the list you just created. Left click on it.
- The click "edit columns" to make changes.
- Add your columns and then you need to save. Right click on the tab where you are creating columns that as an * next to it. The asterisk means you have unsaved content. When you right click you can save it. Else just hit the quick save button at the top ofSPD.
- That's all you have to do. The list should be created and updated on the site now.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your comments. I do that you say and work fine, but my problem is when I try to modify the code of a SP list on SPD, for example, I change the tittle "new camp" and put "new proyect" on the code, when I press "Preview in Browser" button, I can see the changes, moreover, I can save it. but when I click on "new list" on SP, I just see the default list, without any change that I made on SPD

Comment: Try the refresh icon at the top of SP Designer to reload your changes.